# How to specify a list of tests to run in the nightwatch.conf.js file

Tags: nightwatch.js

Is there a way to specify a list of tests to run in the nightwatch.conf.js file?  I see the "filter" option but that takes a single pattern match string.  There's the "exclude" option that takes a list of tests to *exclude*.  Something like an "include" option where you could specify a list of tests would be perfect but I don't see that option.

Answer (score 0):

according to Nightwatch [documentation](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/#test-tags) you can specify a group of tests by adding a tag before your test name

```
'@tags': ['tagName'],
```